# Convert a string representation of a tuple to a tuple

Tags: python, tuples, sys

I got a `tuple` inside another one like :

```
a = ((21.0, 0.0), (27.6, 0.0014), (33.8, 0.0028), (39.6, 0.0041))
```

I convert it to a string to parse it through in cmd to other scripts like

```
a = str(a)
```

Does anyone know an easy way to convert it another way around when a new script got it through sys?

```
a = tuple(a)
```

is not working.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

print(ast.literal_eval(str(a)))
((21.0, 0.0), (27.6, 0.0014), (33.8, 0.0028), (39.6, 0.0041))
```

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Comment: Ok I thought I knew him :)